# Can anyone explain me about boundingbox?

Tags: matlab, cell, bounding-box

Can anyone explain me about boundingbox? I searched it, but I can not find the clear explanation.
Because I need to explain about boundingbox in my paper.
and can anyone explain to me about this function

```
objects{idx} = out(bb(2):bb(2)+bb(4), bb(1):bb(1)+bb(3),:);
```

Thank you :)

Comment: You're writing a paper where you have to explain boundingbox, but need to ask for an explanation on SO..? I think you might want to reconsider that paper!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bounding box is usually an upright box to select a certain part of an image, e.g., when you do object detection, you would define the object by a bounding box around that object in the image.

In this case it seems like the bounding box bb is defined in the following way:

```
bb(2) = top position
bb(4) = height
bb(1) = left position
bb(3) = width
```

This upright rectangle is cropped out from "out", which looks like a multichannel (color?) image.

Comment: Thank you! 
The number 2, 4, 1, and 3. Is it default number? Or we can change it?

Comment: Those are indices. `bb` in this case is a MATLAB array with 4 entries.
Of course, you can change the values AND you can change the definition, e.g. using top position and bottom position instead of using top position and height.

There is no "standard" bounding box format, use whatever is needed for your problem.